# Send Lotus Notes calendar event using PHP mail

Tags: php, calendar, lotus-notes

I would like to ask if it is even possible to create/send email with some information about Lotus Notes calendar event in PHP and send it to aaa@bbb.cc

```
Do it just with a headers:
to: xxxxx
subject: xxxxx
starttime: xxxxx
endtime: xxxxx
eventtype: xxxxx
body: This is my first event
```

I was no able to find any references about email headers, how to create entry to Lotus Notes calendar.

Comment: You're question is a little vague.  Are you trying to send an invitation email to someone and have that invitation show up as an event on his Lotus Notes calendar? Or are you trying to read information from a Lotus Notes calendar event and send that information in the body of an email message to someone?

Answer (score 1):

try this, I hope that are all fields you need.
But you have to test it in lotus-notes.

```
AppointmentType:3
Body:"..."
chair:"Person"
Form:"Appointment"
From:"Person"
StartDate:XX.XX.XXXX
StartTime:XX:XX:XX
STARTDATETIME: XX.XX.XXXX XX:XX:XX CET
EndDate:XX.XX.XXXX
EndTime:XX:XX:XX
ENDDATETIME: XX.XX.XXXX XX:XX:XX CET
RequiredAttendees:"Person1""Person2"...
SendTo:"Person1""Person2"...
```